# QuerySyntaxException when using SQL EXCEPT and count(*)

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails, spring-data

I have a situation in Hibernate where I need to get the count(*) on a SQL EXCEPT query. Below is the query (imitated my original code):

```
String query = """ 
               select count(*) as totalCount 
               from ( select distinct id from Employee 
                      where name like '%Roger% 
                      EXCEPT select distinct id from Manager ) Temporary
               """
```

Now, when I say:

```
hibernateSession.createQuery(query);
```

The below exception is thrown:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
                    unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 36
```

My logs also show the below parsing errors when I catch the exception:

```
org.hibernate.hql.PARSER    line 1:36: unexpected token: (
org.hibernate.hql.PARSER    line 14:315: unexpected token: EXCEPT
org.hibernate.hql.PARSER    line 15:68: unexpected token: from
```

I cannot avoid the count, WHERE or EXCEPT.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using `hibernateSession.createQuery(query)`, hibernate is creating a query using HQL syntax, which doesn't work with your query, as you're using SQL syntax.

You most likely need to use something resembling `hibernateSession.createSQLQuery(query)`.

For more on using native sql queries, see [Native SQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html) in the Hibernate documentation.

The answers to this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636806/difference-between-hibernate-createcriteria-createquery-createsqlquery-functio) might also be useful.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to try createSQLQuery(). However, can I assume a couple of things before going ahead: 1. Can I assume there isn't anything wrong with the Syntax of the query I pasted? 2. My understanding ( may be wrong ) is that createSQLQuery is used when the query input is in native SQL syntax. But in my query am using the Domain names and Property names instead of the SQL Table and Column names. Is it still fine to use createSQLQuery.

Comment: Sorry, no.  I guess I didn't see that.  I think you'll have to use the table names and column names instead, if you're going this way.  It has to really be SQL.

Comment: That's bad :( I really don't want to write native SQL. Seems I have to figure a way around. Thank you Don.

Comment: You might be able to replace the EXCEPT clause with a NOT EXISTS clause, which would be valid in HQL.  Not sure about the subselect.  I don't actually use HQL all that much.  With criteria you can mix in SQL restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this query instead? Replaced EXCEPT with NOT EXISTS.

```
String query = """ 
           select count(*) as totalCount 
           from ( select distinct id from Employee as emp
                  where emp.name like '%Roger% 
                  and not exists ( 
                      from Manager as m where emp.id = m.id
                  ) 
                ) Temporary
           """
```

Comment: I tried your recommendations. But they didn't work. Neither the triple " and nor the NOT EXISTS. Moreover, I don't think NOT EXISTS suits my requirement as it is not same as EXCEPT. Nevertheless, I did try as I needed the query to work, but in vain. Do let me know if you have any more ideas.