# hql query to get last 1 month records

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I need to fetch records of last month using hql earlier i used to fetch records using sql query but now i need to fetch records of 1 month span.for example today's date is 15-Dec-2014 I want to get records between 15-Nov-2014  to 14-Dec-2014 records.

Here is Mysql query:

```
   SELECT fds.EXISTED_PRODUCT_ID,fds.Product_Name,fds.PRODUCT_CREATED_DATE FROM 
     F_PRODUCT_DATA_STATISTICS fds where fds.CREATED_TS BETWEEN 
SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND NOW()
```

Frankly, I don't have any idea about how to write above query in HQl.
Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this, I couldn't test, if you it has a error please inform me;

```
String hqlQuery =" SELECT fds.EXISTED_PRODUCT_ID,fds.Product_Name,fds.PRODUCT_CREATED_DATE FROM F_PRODUCT_DATA_STATISTICS fds where fds.CREATED_TS BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND current_date()"; 
query = session.createSQLQuery(hqlQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick help @semih.I run the above query in my application I got error when I use session.createQuery() but when I use session.createSQLQuery() it fetching records

Comment: I am glad to help you. I also editted as createSQLQuery. Could you mark this answer as correct, it maybe helps others.

Comment: Hey @semih I have a doubt..If i use createSQLQuery(query) Isit works if i change mydatabase **like Eg:Mysql** to someother like **oracle or IBM DB2..etc**

Comment: Yes It works, with select query, createSQLQuery() must be used.

Comment: This post helps you; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636806/difference-between-hibernate-createcriteria-createquery-createsqlquery-functio