# Hibernate, Can't execute native SQL update query that has JOINS

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

```
public void do_UPDATE(Set<Long> customerIdSet) {

    final String query = 
        "UPDATE product_orders po " +
        "INNER join customer c " +
        "ON po.order_id = c.order_id " +
        "SET po.updated_on = now() " +
        "WHERE c.customer_id IN (:customerIdSet)";

        List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<Long>(customerIdSet.size());

        for(final Long id : customerIdSet) {
            ids.add(id);
        }

    _sessionFactory
        .getCurrentSession()
        .createSQLQuery(query)
        .setParameterList("customerIdSet", ids)
        .executeUpdate();

}
```

I'm getting a SQLGrammarException. This query actually runs in a real MySQL console, but why doesn't Hibernate think it is the right syntax?

Comment: `.createQuery(query)` ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636806/difference-between-hibernate-createcriteria-createquery-createsqlquery-functio

Comment: that is for creating HQL queries.

Comment: `.setParameter(` then? since your `customerIdSet` is not `List` type

Comment: making the set into a list and calling setParameterList still doesn't work

Comment: making what!? provide new code if any

Comment: the the argument into a `List` still breaks, the exception is: can't prepare statement, see the edit

Comment: according to your new code shouldn't it be `ids` instead of `customerIdSet` when  `.setParameterList("customerIdSet", customerIdSet)`?

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake... this is driving me crazy. the SQL code works, hibernate just sucks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My platform would not execute statements with INNER JOIN in them, so the solution was to use a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem was with `INNER JOIN` I would try to modify query to:

```
"UPDATE product_orders po " +
"INNER join customer c " +
"ON po.order_id = c.order_id " +
"AND c.customer_id IN (:customerIdSet) "+
"SET po.updated_on = now() "
```

Comment: JDBC should be able to hand STANDARD queries, I changed it to use a subquery